# Can a keyboard install software on a PC?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Windows 7.  I plugged in a keyboard that my wife picked up at a grab pile.  Shortly after booting with it connected, I noticed a new task running - an install screen for 'Razer Synapse'.  (The keyboard turns out to be a 'Razer [something]'.)  I closed this window, and did not do anything to install it.  However, Task Manager showed a couple of Razer-named tasks running, and msconfig showed at least one Razer-named service running.

Question: can a (USB) keyboard install software on its own?

Thanks.

(Some really bad things happened after that.  I will leave that for another post.)

Comment: Certannly there are USB devices that have 2  functions, the second being a storage device of some sort with a driver or software in it. But you really want to know most if a "Razer keyboard" does, and therefore your title should reflect that. so other razer users will answer.

Comment: Yes; In theory a keyboard could install software

Comment: Sounds like a driver.

Comment: See [What is the danger of inserting an untrusted USB device?](http://superuser.com/questions/709275/what-is-the-danger-of-inserting-and-browsing-an-untrusted-usb-drive/709302#709302)

Comment: Why the downvote?  It would be helpful to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razer-named tasks are the tasks used by the Razer driver.
The driver should be let to be installed and active since it drastically improves your keyboard functionality (including response time).