# How can I browse an untrusted USB flash drive safely?

Tags: security, usb-flash-drive

Say I have a USB flash drive I found lying on the ground. I want to see if it has any information that could help me return it to its owner, but I live in an urban society. It could easily contain malware and be lying on the ground in wait for its next victim.

How can I browse the contents of this USB flash drive safely?

Comment: My 1st thought is you boot the PC up with a liveCD

Comment: @Moab [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/709275/what-is-the-danger-of-inserting-and-browsing-an-untrusted-usb-drive?rq=1) has answers listing lots of dangers of untrusted USBs that can indeed jump off the drive into a PC.

Comment: use  virtual machine and open the pendrive

Comment: @moab exactly opposite - there are still code execution bugs found in filesystem mounting, autorun.inf handling etc.

Comment: Find somebody you don't like and plug it in their computer.

Comment: Use Virtual machine, find it mounted first in the host OS and oh, ooops!

Comment: Related: [Safely opening a suspect USB Drive](//superuser.com/q/167878/150988),  [Is there any way to safely examine the contents of a USB memory stick?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103088/34757),  [What is the danger of inserting and browsing an untrusted USB drive?](//superuser.com/q/709275/150988),  [How can a flash drive spread a virus?](//superuser.com/q/93939/150988),  and  [How can USB sticks be dangerous?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/102873/34757),  and probably more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were many options to open it, but in case of safety concern it will consume more time:

1. Open it up through some live CD version of Linux. If the USB flash drive was infected it would infect only the OS on the live CD.
2. Boot the OS in a virtual machine and test the USB flash drive[Note: You can set the guest OS to detect USB first which would disable the host USB detection].
3. If you are using a Windows machine: Disable `autorun.inf` on a local computer.
4. If you are on mac mount the USB as [readonly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146436/63269)
5. You could disable autorun in mac by following this [steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/136422/) :

You need to remove the auto launch job with the `launchctl` command.

For example, in my case I have already installed a modem manufactured by ZTE. So I searched for LAUNCHD listings using the `launchctl list` command and grepped for those modem strings.

```
launchctl list | grep -i zte
```

Showing:

```
5681    -   cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist
```

If you do not find your app, then output all the jobs to a file. This awk command tries to overcome the chance that you may have spaces in your launchd job name.

```
launchctl list 2>/dev/null | awk '
{ x="\""substr($0, match($0, $3), 100)"\""; print x; system("launchctl list " x) }
' > launchList.txt
```

Open launchList.txt. The name of the launchd job will be shown in "..." above the {} block where you hopefully find a "Mobile Partner" or "AutoOpen" string.

Perhaps inspect the item to be more confident before removal. Surround by "" if there are spaces in the job name.

```
launchctl list "cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist"
```

Then just remove it. This is the command to stop the auto load. Be very sure you are removing the correct agent or deamon.

```
launchctl remove "cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist"
```

Add it again if you want, using the full path of the PLIST file.

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist
```

Scan through a computer and all USB flash drives regularly.

Note for [BADUSB](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/07/this-thumbdrive-hacks-computers-badusb-exploit-makes-devices-turn-evil/) :

> When you plug a USB device into a computer, the device tells the
>   computer what sort of thing it is, so the computer can select the
>   appropriate driver. For example, a thumb drive declares itself as a
>   "USB Mass Storage" device, while a keyboard is a "Human Interface
>   Device".
>
> BadUSB is a technique for re-writing the firmware of a plugged-in USB
>   device from the computer. For example, it could make a thumb drive
>   identify itself as a mouse and cause the pointer to jump around at
>   random. Or it could make the thumb drive identify as a USB hub with
>   connected keyboard and mass storage, that when plugged in types a
>   sequence of keystrokes that causes a program on the thumb drive to be
>   run.

If you were using linux and wish to prevent against badusb :

BadUSB attacks are based on the fact that computers allow and enable HID devices on all usb ports. Faked network adapters are no real danger. My answer tries do describe how to use udev to temporarily disable the addition of new HID devices

For **preparation**, create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbblock.rules` with the content:

```
#ACTION=="add", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="03" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/../authorized'"
```

If you want to block other classes too, then [look up the class number](http://www.usb.org/developers/defined_class/), and copy the line, and change the class.

Now you can **block** all new HID devices using the command

```
sed -i 's/#//' /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbblock.rules; udevadm control --reload-rules
```

and **unblock** with:

```
sed -i 's/^/#/' /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbblock.rules; udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Before you shut down, **always unblock**, as the setting is persistent, and your "good" HID devices would be rejected on reboot.

I don't know whether you can edit the temporary rules directory, but if changes there affect the behaviour, you should edit that instead, as then you don't need to unblock before shutdown.

BADUSB Credits source : Security [DMZ](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64524/how-to-prevent-badusb-attacks-on-linux-desktop)

Comment: Does your answer also apply to compromised firmwares such as BadUSB? More specifically, can the USB firmware of the physical USB port on the physical machine be affected by a USB drive whose firmware is compromised?

Comment: Also if mounting to Linux, use the mount options `noexec,nosuid,nodev`.

Comment: On MAC, does mounting the USB stick readonly really protect my HDD? Sounds to me like it protects the USB stick, not the HDD.

Comment: Option 2 is not quite safe, as before you transfer USB control to VM, OS sees it. At least that's the case with VMWare.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It's worth mentioning in the answer then, as it's a crucial point and not all VM software support it

Comment: @DarkWanderer updated answer thanx

Answer (score 1):

Disable autorun in windows as mentioned here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967715

After that you could safely browse files. If you do not execute/open files which could countain viruses/malware, you are safe.

Malware can be placed in these files: .exe, .dll, .scr, .doc(m)**, .xls(m), .xlsb, .ppt(m), .dot(m), .xlt(m), .pot(m), .bat, .cmd, etc.

Malware cannot be places in: .jpeg, .gif, .png, .txt, .docx, .xlsx, .pptx

** May be either the .doc or .docm versions

Comment: Take attention that -x extensions of Microsoft Office (.docx, .pptx, .xlsx) cannot contain macros so cannot have viruses. https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Introduction-to-new-file-name-extensions-ECA81DCB-5626-4E5B-8362-524D13AE4EC1

Comment: so editors of my answer are WRONG

Comment: One issue of which to be wary is that not all usb devices that appear to be flash drives are actually just flash drives.  There may be additional hardware on the board that interacts with the computer beyond the awareness of the user.  This means a user may not need to consciously execute any application on the device to be compromised or affected.